# Handsontable implementation

Tags: jquery, handsontable

I followed the steps suggested by User: PostureOfLearning and came up with a test code , which i Pasted below. It is working fine in Chrome, but not in IE.Please let me know, if i need to make any changes to make the code work in IE.Thanks in advance.

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>  
 <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
 <script src="jquery.plugin.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
 <script src="custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
 <script src="C:\wamp\www\rrr\bin\jquery-handsontable-master\dist_wc\x-handsontable\jquery.handsontable.full.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="C:\wamp\www\rrr\bin\jquery-handsontable-master\dist_wc\x-handsontable\jquery.handsontable.full.css">
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="handsontableDivID">
 <script>
  var data = [
   ["", "Maserati", "Mazda", "Mercedes", "Mini", "Mitsubishi"],
   ["2009", 0, 2941, 4303, 354, 5814],
   ["2010", 5, 2905, 2867, 412, 5284],
   ["2011", 4, 2517, 4822, 552, 6127],
   ["2012", 2, 2422, 5399, 776, 4151]
             ];
  var config = {
    data: data,
    minRows: 5,
    minCols: 6,
    minSpareRows: 1,
    autoWrapRow: true,
    colHeaders: true,
    contextMenu: true
    };
    $("#handsontableDivID").handsontable(config);
   </script>
   </body>
   </html>
```

The errors i am getting are
SCRIPT1014: Invalid character 
jquery.handsontable.full.js, line 1 character 1
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'handsontable' 
test1.html, line 32 character 1

Comment: http://handsontable.com/demo/ajax.html shows an example of reading data from an existing URL ("json/load.json") and saving it to another URL ("json/save.json")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you extracted the zip file into your web site solution and that you also have jQuery installed.

On the web pages, you will need to make sure you add the script pointing to the js file you extracted. Something like:

```
<script src="~/js/Handsontable/jquery.handsontable.js"></script>
```

And add styling:

```
<link href="~/css/jquery.handsontable.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

And some sample js:

```
var config = {} //Any config would be done here
$("#handsontableDivID").handsontable(config); //this initializes the table
```

To get the data out of handsontable and send back to server:

```
vara data = $("#handsontableDivID").handsontable('getInstance').getData();
```

Look through the examples and how to's:

http://handsontable.com/index.html

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will do the suggested steps and let you know how it went.

Comment: @user2791530 It looks like it is not 'finding' the js file. Change from 'src="C:..."' to something like 'src="/rrr/..."'.